# Atom throwing babel-eslint error constantly

Tags: babeljs, atom-editor, eslint

At first, atom would throw this error if `eslint` was not saved as a dependency in a React project and it would pop up as a red notification.
Now I am working in a directory that is **not** a git repo and it will incessantly launch this error whenever I try and type. Here's what I'm seeing:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'babel-eslint'
    at Object.ModuleResolver.resolve (/Users/josetello/.atom/packages/linter-eslint/node_modules/eslint/lib/util/module-resolver.js:75:19)
```

I've tried updating eslint/babel packages in atom, uninstalling them, looking around in the atom config file for hints as to what this might be, but no luck. It's driving me nuts - anyone else run into something similar?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may be able to fix this by changing directory to:

```
~/.atom/packages/linter-eslint/
```

Then running:

```
npm install babel-eslint
```

You will need to ensure that you have [Node](https://nodejs.org/en/) installed and `npm` in your path for the above to work.  I also recommend reporting the issue as a [defect](https://github.com/iancmyers/atom-eslint/issues/) on the projects GitHub repository.

Answer (score 1):

Try this setting:

[image]

You don't need to add `babel-eslint` as a dependency. Just check this setting in Atom.